# Python making custom overloaded operators

Tags: python

Is there a simple way in python to make a custom overloaded operator (I am aware of the default ones).

An example of what I mean: say I am working on a vector class, and I want to do a vector cross product which I want to represent by the character X , there is no default overloaded operators that does this. (Therefore, I would like to know if this is possible, as it is in C++ for example).

Thanks

Comment: Instead of defining your own vector class, have you considered using `numpy`?